# How to configure AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute for playing different audios to built-in speaker and headphones (or bluetooth headphones)?

Tags: ios, swift, avkit

I found such info:

> Important: The built-in speaker may be used only if no other eligible output ports (USB, HDMI, LineOut) are connected.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html

But standard iOS Clock app can use  built-in speaker when 3.5 jack headphones connected.

What about bluetooth headphones? Can I send different audio streams to 
built-in speaker and bluetooth headphones at the same time using AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute?

Comment: Found in official apple doc about 'allowBluetooth' for audioSession

 "You can set this option only if the audio session category is AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions/1616518-allowbluetooth

Comment: Now I have another question: can I achieve my goal using CoreBluetooth instead?